# Redefined RDF properties in Wikidata

Tags: sparql, rdf, semantic-web, wikidata, knowledge-graph

Wikidata seems to redefine common RDF properties such as:

- `rdf:type` ([P31](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P31) in Wikidata),
- `rdfs:subClassOf` ([P279](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P279))
- `rdfs:subPropertyOf` ([P1647](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P1647))
- ...

What's the motivation behind this? Why not just use the RDF properties, making it more similar to other knowledge graphs and therefore easier to query?

Comment: Then how all these derived predicates would look like? — https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikibase/Indexing/RDF_Dump_Format#Predicates

Comment: Let's say Wikidata data model is somewhat "special" and honestly doesn't really fit into the RDF data model with its "limitations" like  only having binary relations and that reification support nobody wants to use because it's too verbose. RDF* would have simplified some of the more complex patterns in the Wikidata RDF model, but it's just a non-standard extension. And the next step now is SPARQL 1.2 and GQL

Comment: thanks to both of you, I tried to compile your comments on the answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following up on [Stanislav's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58083726/redefined-rdf-properties-in-wikidata?noredirect=1#comment102562244_58083726) and [AKSW's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58083726/redefined-rdf-properties-in-wikidata?noredirect=1#comment102567894_58083726) comments, I did a bit of research.

As far as I understand it (improvements/corrections are welcome), Wikidata has its [own data model](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikibase/DataModel) (it is not natively represented as an RDF graph -- [quick introduction here](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikibase/DataModel/Primer)). For example, Wikidata statements are [ranked](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikibase/DataModel#Ranks_of_Statements),  they can be linked to [references](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikibase/DataModel#ReferenceRecords), etc.

These features can be replicated in RDF (using, for example, [RDF reification](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-primer/#reification)) but that can be somewhat verbose and/or complex. As a result, Wikidata defines its own properties and classes, while still linking them to the equivalent RDF constructs.

Worth reading:

- https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikibase/Indexing/RDF_Dump_Format
- http://aidanhogan.com/docs/reification-wikidata-rdf-sparql.pdf
- http://www.snee.com/bobdc.blog/2017/04/the-wikidata-data-model-and-yo.html